# Как изменить или удалить элементы сайта в Android WebView?

Tags: java, html, android, android-webview

**Есть такой сайт: [ссылка](https://overframe.gg/build/new/primary-weapons/)**
(обязательно нажмите на кнопку **toggle device toolbar** в инструментах разработчика перед его просмотром, ведь моё приложение работает на андройде). Мне нужно убрать все тэги `nav` и их детей.

Я попробовал такой код, но почему-то ничего не получилось:

```
public void editWeapons(Context context) {
    try {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Loading page... Please wait!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("Ready");
        weapon.webViewA.evaluateJavascript("(function(){const navs = document.querySelectorAll('nav');navs.forEach(el => {el.remove();console.log(el)})}())", null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Connection problems!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Я проверял в браузерной консоли на сайте js код:

```js
(function(){const navs = document.querySelectorAll('nav');navs.forEach(el => {el.remove();console.log(el)})}())
```

И он прекрасно работал, а точнее удалял все `nav` и писал всё в консоли, но, когда я пытаюсь запустить его в `webView.evaluateJavascript()` он ничего не делает при загрузке страницы.

Консоль выводит ошибку `[ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(342)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS` и `[INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "Error: Minified React error #425;`, и ссылку, содержащую ещё одну ошибку:
`Text content does not match server-rendered HTML`, думаю стоит добавить тег `HTML` в вопрос.
**Как сделать так, чтобы код заработал?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается сайт просто не успевал прогрузиться, если кому-то надо вот конечный код:

```
public void editWeapons() {
    try {
        Toast.makeText(site.context, "Loading page... Please wait!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("Ready");
        site.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
                site.webView.evaluateJavascript("(function(){const navs = document.querySelectorAll('nav');navs.forEach(el => {el.remove();console.log(el)})}())", null);
                System.out.println("okay");
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(site.context, "Connection problems!" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```